datetimepicker minDate/maxDate in adminLTE template
I can't get minDate and maxDate to work on the two date fields.
Selected by date from the first field, the second does not set minDate.
I followed the example on https://getdatepicker.com/4/
I don't understand if it's a problem with the datepicker resources present in the adminLTE template or I'm doing something wrong...
This is my test page: https://advertising.esprimo.com/insieme/
<div class="input-group date" id="da_data_1" data-target-input="nearest">
  <div class="input-group-prepend" data-target="#da_data_1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar" ></i></div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="da_data_1" id="data_inizio_1" value="" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#da_data_1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
</div>

<div class="input-group date" id="a_data_2" data-target-input="nearest">
  <div class="input-group-prepend" data-target="#a_data_2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="a_data_2" id="data_fine_2" value="" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#a_data_2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
  $('#da_data_1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  });
  $('#a_data_2').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  });
  $("#da_data_1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#a_data_2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
  });
  $("#a_data_2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#da_data_1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
  });
});                                    
</script>


Resolved!
$("#da_data_1").on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
  $('#a_data_1').datetimepicker('minDate', e.date);
});
$("#a_data_1").on("change.datetimepicker", function (e) {
  $('#da_data_1').datetimepicker('maxDate', e.date);
});

the correct examples to copy for adminlte are these: https://getdatepicker.com/5-4/Usage/#linked-pickers
